# No response when trying to start hive metastore server

Tags: hive

I'm using this instruction to install hive in mac m1. [https://techblost.com/how-to-install-hive-on-mac-with-homebrew/]. I follow all the steps and when I try to run `./hive --service metastore &` I got nothing. I don't have any errors and response.

This is my hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hive.querylog.location</name>
    <value>/Users/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/log/hive.log</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.querylog.enable.plan.progress</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.log.explain.output</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>***</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
```

And I can use `mysql -u hive -p` with my password to log into mysql to query.
I spent the whole day to find the solutions but no answers solve my issue. Please help me.
Many thanks.